# Why can't I std::move std::unique_ptrs between std::sets?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, move-semantics, unique-ptr

I really want to move some `unique_ptr`s from one `std::set` into another:

```
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>

int main()
{
   std::set<std::unique_ptr<int>> a;
   std::set<std::unique_ptr<int>> b;

   a.insert({0, std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(42))});

   std::move(a.begin(), a.end(), std::inserter(b, b.end()));
}
```

However, my GCC 4.8.5 on CentOS 7 is distinctly unhappy:

> ```
> [root@localhost ~]# g++ test.cpp -std=c++11 -o test
> In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/set:60:0,
>                  from test.cpp:2:
> /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_tree.h: In instantiation of ‘std::_Rb_tree_node<_Val>::_Rb_tree_node(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {const std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> >&}; _Val = std::unique_ptr<int>]’:
> /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ext/new_allocator.h:120:4:   required from ‘void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::unique_ptr<int> >; _Args = {const std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> >&}; _Tp = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::unique_ptr<int> >]’
> /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/alloc_traits.h:254:4:   required from ‘static typename std::enable_if<std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::__construct_helper<_Tp, _Args>::value, void>::type std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::_S_construct(_Alloc&, _Tp*, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::unique_ptr<int> >; _Args = {const std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> >&}; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::unique_ptr<int> > >; typename std::enable_if<std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::__construct_helper<_Tp, _Args>::value, void>::type = void]’
> /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/alloc_traits.h:393:57:   required from ‘static decltype (_S_construct(__a, __p, (forward<_Args>)(std::allocator_traits::construct::__args)...)) std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::construct(_Alloc&, _Tp*, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::unique_ptr<int> >; _Args = {const std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> >&}; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::unique_ptr<int> > >; decltype (_S_construct(__a, __p, (forward<_Args>)(std::allocator_traits::construct::__args)...)) = <type error>]’
> /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_tree.h:408:36:   required from ‘std::_Rb_tree_node<_Val>* std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_create_node(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {const std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> >&}; _Key = std::unique_ptr<int>; _Val = std::unique_ptr<int>; _KeyOfValue = std::_Identity<std::unique_ptr<int> >; _Compare = std::less<std::unique_ptr<int> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<int> >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Link_type = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::unique_ptr<int> >*]’
> /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_tree.h:1023:66:   required from ‘std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_insert_(std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Base_ptr, std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Base_ptr, _Arg&&) [with _Arg = const std::unique_ptr<int>&; _Key = std::unique_ptr<int>; _Val = std::unique_ptr<int>; _KeyOfValue = std::_Identity<std::unique_ptr<int> >; _Compare = std::less<std::unique_ptr<int> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<int> >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::unique_ptr<int> >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Base_ptr = std::_Rb_tree_node_base*]’
> /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_tree.h:1482:33:   required from ‘std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_insert_unique_(std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator, _Arg&&) [with _Arg = const std::unique_ptr<int>&; _Key = std::unique_ptr<int>; _Val = std::unique_ptr<int>; _KeyOfValue = std::_Identity<std::unique_ptr<int> >; _Compare = std::less<std::unique_ptr<int> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<int> >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::unique_ptr<int> >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::unique_ptr<int> >]’
> /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_tree.h:1722:37:   required from ‘void std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_insert_unique(_II, _II) [with _InputIterator = const std::unique_ptr<int>*; _Key = std::unique_ptr<int>; _Val = std::unique_ptr<int>; _KeyOfValue = std::_Identity<std::unique_ptr<int> >; _Compare = std::less<std::unique_ptr<int> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<int> >]’
> /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_set.h:518:4:   required from ‘void std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(_InputIterator, _InputIterator) [with _InputIterator = const std::unique_ptr<int>*; _Key = std::unique_ptr<int>; _Compare = std::less<std::unique_ptr<int> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<int> >]’
> /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_set.h:530:9:   required from ‘void std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(std::initializer_list<_Tp>) [with _Key = std::unique_ptr<int>; _Compare = std::less<std::unique_ptr<int> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<int> >]’
> test.cpp:9:49:   required from here
> /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_tree.h:140:49: error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = int; _Dp = std::default_delete<int>]’
>     _M_value_field(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...) { }
>                                                  ^
> In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/memory:81:0,
>                  from test.cpp:1:
> /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/unique_ptr.h:273:7: error: declared here
>        unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
>        ^
> ```

What do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: _"What do I need to do to make this work?"_ Does it work with a newer GCC version?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: [Apparently not](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/909023cd2804d25c)

Comment: Well, to try could help to distinguish it's a GCC bug, or a more fundamental problem, as long you're sure having applied standards conforming code.

Comment: I don't understand how I'm the only person to have up voted this.

Comment: @Barry: Neither do I, given that the score is 2 :)

Comment: Upvoted for the thought of *asking* this, and thereby uncovering relevant new functionality in upcoming C++ standard.

Comment: Isn't this consice error message self explanatory?

Comment: @LiorKogan: No. It shows that a copy is being attempted. The problem was I forgot what `std::move` doesn't do, and couldn't understand why a copy would be attempted and how to make it not be attempted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You basically cannot do this in C++14 since a set's elements are `const`. Since moving is a modifying operation, you would need some way to get non-`const` access to the elements and there's simply no way to do this.

But you *will* be able to do this in C++17 with the new [`merge()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/merge) member function:

```
b.merge(std::move(a));
```

Similarly, there will be an `extract()` member function that will remove and give you non-`const` access to a single node.

---

Of course, you could always use a type like (with h/t by [T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38679108/why-cant-i-stdmove-stdunique-ptrs-between-stdsets/38679145?noredirect=1#comment64738223_38679145)):

```
struct Hack {
    mutable std::unique_ptr<T> p;
    T* raw_ptr;

    bool operator<(Hack const& h) const {
        // implemented in terms of the raw ptr
        // not the unique ptr
    }
};
```

Moving from `p` is now safe (it's mutable) and as long as you **just** move (and not `reset()`) and implement the ordering in terms of the raw pointer, then you should preserve the set ordering as well. You have to store two pointers now, but this should avoid UB in C++11.

Comment: But I'm taking the elements out of the set. Why should key immutability affect that?

Comment: @Lightness You simply have no non-`const` access to them.

Comment: No but the standard library does, and I'm asking the standard library to move the elements.

Comment: You're not taking elements out of the set. You are trying to modify elements.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: No, I'm not. Those elements won't exist in the set after the `std::move` call. There is no way for me to observe modifications to those elements. I am trying to take them out of the set. I see no reason why the standard library implementation can't make it work. I accept now that it doesn't, but I see no reason why it couldn't be made to. Indeed, that seems to be what `merge` will do.

Comment: In an ideal world, a "set-aware" move operation would be able to move from the elements and erase them from the tree in one [observable] fell swoop, without breaking any invariants. Maybe there's some reason I'm not aware of that that's infeasible or intractible or just not worthwhile. Either way, I'm left with a seriously handicapped container.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I'm not sure what you're saying. Of course they would still exist in the set. `std::move` doesn't remove elements from the container it operates on. It moves them, which you, I'm sure, are well aware, is a modifying operation.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: _"`std::move` doesn't remove elements from the container it operates on"_ Ooh.... yes that's the reason. Why is it that everything named "move" in the standard library is named _badly_? ;) Okay, so yes, indeed, I forgot that I'm operating on ranges not containers. Drat.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Consider writing this as an answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:  `extract`will remove a node from the `set` and give you non-const access to the node so you can move from it:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/extract

Comment: @HowardHinnant: That's excellent. Unfortunately, not of any use in C++11 :(

Comment: The idea on how to accomplish this came very late in the game on C++11, and then was rejected during C++14 development.  The wheels of progress do tend to grind slowly...

Comment: You could go const_cast followed by erase.  You will be in an undefined state between the const_cast/move and the erase.  But it should work.

Comment: @Howard Aren't the nodes declared const pre-C++17? So wouldn't the `const_cast` be UB?

Comment: @Barry: Fortunately the container sizes I'm working with mean I can switch to `std::vector` for now. I think.

Comment: @Barry: The actual move does the UB, not the cast.

Comment: Yes.  But the nodes will not live in ROM.  So you can get away with it.  Otherwise the std::lib implementor couldn't get away with doing this hack for you in C++17. ;-)

Comment: @HowardHinnant: Hmm, I don't think I'm confident enough that erase won't rely on the value of the moved-from element for re-arranging the tree structure. Even if you can personally guarantee it for some specific version, I reckon there's generally enough risk here to warrant avoiding it for production code.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:  I don't blame you.  It is very hackish.  This is why it was important for the std::lib implementor to do this for you.

Comment: @Lightness I added a hack to the answer using `mutable`. That may actually work and be non-UB.

Comment: I'm not sure that is safe. You couldn't define a stable ordering for `Hack`.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: And I'm glad that they did :)

Comment: `Hack` can store a raw pointer to the thing and compare that.

Comment: @T.C.. Mmm that'd do it. So then the only problem is doubling storage ^_^ At that point, frankly, might be easier to give `Hack` a deleter, turning it into a smart pointer implementation. Like a `movable_unique_ptr_that_can_be_used_in_sets_even_after_youve_moved_from_it`

Comment: @T.C. You mean both right - both a `mutable` `unique_ptr` and the raw?

Comment: `b.merge(a);` is sufficient. The `std::move` is superfluous.

Comment: @T.C. Ah. For some reason only saw the rvalue reference overload the first time around. Still, I like `move()` just for the added visual cue.

Comment: @Barry `merge` is not enough cue for you?

Comment: @T.C. Not for me. I could easily see `merge()` as doing a range-copy or something. YMMV.

Comment: FYI in the end I used a vector instead :D

Answer (score 4):

The elements of a std::set are **const**, mainly because a std::set is ordered by the value of the elements. Changing the values could change the ordering which--as consequence--will corrupt the internal representation of the std::set.

Moving a std::unique_ptr out of a std::set will certainly render the std::set unusable.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do this using C++11 in g++ 4.8.2:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

// One possible solution:
template <typename Type>
void move_set_unique_ptr( 
    std::set<std::unique_ptr<Type>> & source,
    std::set<std::unique_ptr<Type>> & destination
) {
    for ( const std::unique_ptr<Type> & source_unique_ptr : source ) {
        destination.insert(
            std::move( const_cast<std::unique_ptr<Type> &>( source_unique_ptr ) )
        );
    }
    source.clear();
}

// Not part of a solution ... just for use with std::cout:
template <typename Type>
std::ostream & operator << (
    std::ostream & o,
    const std::set<std::unique_ptr<Type>> & s
);

int main() {
    using type = int;

    std::set<std::unique_ptr<type>> a;
    std::set<std::unique_ptr<type>> b;

    // std::make_unique<T> is not available in C++11

    a.insert( nullptr );
    a.insert( std::unique_ptr<type>( new type{ 62 } ) );
    a.insert( std::unique_ptr<type>( new type{ 42 } ) );
    a.insert( std::unique_ptr<type>( new type{ 22 } ) );

    b.insert( std::unique_ptr<type>( new type{ 41 } ) );
    b.insert( std::unique_ptr<type>( new type{ 42 } ) );
    b.insert( std::unique_ptr<type>( new type{ 43 } ) );
    b.insert( nullptr );

    std::cout << "a: " << a << '\n';
    std::cout << "b: " << b << '\n';

    move_set_unique_ptr(a, b);

    std::cout << "a: " << a << '\n';
    std::cout << "b: " << b << '\n';
}

// Not part of a solution ... just for use with std::cout:
template <typename Type>
std::ostream & operator << (
    std::ostream & o,
    const std::set<std::unique_ptr<Type>> & s
) {
    auto i = std::begin( s );
    auto end = std::end( s );
    o << '{';
    if ( i != end ) {
        auto print = [ &o, &i ]() {
            o << i->get() << ": " << ( *i == nullptr ? Type{} : **i );
        };
        o << ' '; print();
        for ( ++i; i != end; ++i ) {
            o << ", "; print();
        }
        o << ' ';
    }
    o << '}';
    return o;
}
```

This will output something like the following:

```
a: { 0: 0, 0x8f3c50: 62, 0x8f3ca0: 42, 0x8f3cf0: 22 }
b: { 0: 0, 0x8f3d40: 41, 0x8f3d90: 42, 0x8f3de0: 43 }
a: {}
b: { 0: 0, 0x8f3c50: 62, 0x8f3ca0: 42, 0x8f3cf0: 22, 0x8f3d40: 41, 0x8f3d90: 42, 0x8f3de0: 43 }
```

Comment: There is no undefined behavior (UB) here because we are only casting const away on a std::unique_ptr<Type> in order to use std::move and destination.insert( std::unique_ptr<Type> && ) ... all of which are well defined. Moreover, there are no calls to source that can trigger a reordering of its elements between the std::move of its first std::unique_ptr<Type> element to the source.clear() call. Therefore, all behavior is defined.

Comment: What's well-defined about performing a mutating operation on an object you've promised not to mutate?