# The std::pair in the std::map is returned as const

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

My example code is

```
class A
{
    int a = 0;
public:
    void setA(const int value)
    {
        a = value;
    }
};

std::map<std::string, std::set<A>> Map{{"A", {}}};
Map.rbegin()->second.rbegin()->setA(2);
```

I get the following error: "Member function 'setA' not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const A', but function is not marked const"

My question is why rbegin() returns a const pointer to A? Or why is the std:pair's second a const in the std::map?

Comment: Because `std::map` is a tree structure. You can't change the value of its elements, without breaking the structure itself. Try `std::map<int, int>`. (The same applies for `std::set` by the way.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Even though, I could potentially be needing to modify only the second (the value) of the pair? In that case the structure of the tree would not be invalidated right?

Comment: You can modify the *set*, but you can't modify the *set's contents* through its iterators. You also don't have any elements in your set (you'd need to initialise `Map{{"A", {{}}}}` with extra {})

Comment: You can use operator[] to change the value associated with a key.

Comment: In constructing a [MCVE] you should have discovered that the map is irrelevant.

Comment: @DeiDei: That is not true. It is only the keys that you cannot change.

Comment: And please stop answering in the comments section where proper peer review cannot be performed. This is a Q&A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All `std::set` elements are exposed in `const` fashion. That's because they're both keys and values, and if you could modify keys willy-nilly then you'd ruin the tree structure inside the set.

[It is currently not possible to directly modify set elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38679145/560648). You will have to remove then re-insert.

(This has nothing to do with the encapsulating map.)

Answer (score 2):

Basically, `rbegin()` returns a *reverse iterator* which points to an object of type `A` which is stored in the `std::set` in a *const manner*.

The reason behind such behaviour is quite simple: it is necessary to protect `std::set` from inadvertent changes of elements which are stored inside.

You should remember, that `std::set` stores its elements in a tree-like data structure to ensure fast search/insert/remove operations. Possible changes of elements inside `std::set` might lead to wrong elements comparison and corruption of data structure, that is why all iterators return by `begin()`/`end()` methods and their analogues expose elements in a *const fashion*.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/rbegin  rbegin doesn't return a const reverse iterator unless the receiver is const qualified

Comment: @xaxxon as far as I know, for `std::set` reverse_iterator and const_reverse_iterator should be the same typedefs.

Comment: That seems to be true for c++11 and beyond: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set  but not prior.

Comment: @xaxxon yes, exactly.

Comment: @xaxxon I don't like the previous wording, because it might be misleading. I've edited the answer. Thank you for pointing me.